# How to match string with escaped quote character in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In PhpMyAdmin I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM myrecords where TITLE LIKE "%\\\"%"
```

To filter out badly saved records that have `"` sign escaped with `\` sign. It should be just `"`. So I need to find only these records with `\"` and replace it with `"` only. But when I use the query above to filter the `\"` I get records with `\"` as well like the records with `"`.

How to make this query get only records with `\"` and not `"` alone?

Comment: try -> `'%\\"%'` using single quotes to surround the whole string and only escaping the back slash

Comment: It looks like it should work already, but your query may be getting unescaped by phpMyAdmin before MySQL sees it. Can you try the command-line client?

Comment: @hvd Not really because i dont have access to it. And i use only phpMyAdmin to edit data in table.

Comment: @tomaszs In that case, what you could try is escape every `\ `, to get `"%\\\\\\"%"`. *If* my guess is right, that should work. If my guess is wrong, it won't :)

Comment: @hvd I get error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%"' at line 1

Comment: @paul also i get error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%"' at line 1

Comment: @ManseUK The same for your version.

Comment: @tomaszs In that case, no idea right now, but if you don't get an answer by the time I get the chance to check, I'll see if I can get the same error you're getting.

Comment: another guess... `SELECT * FROM myrecords where TITLE REGEXP '\\"' = 1`

Comment: @tomaszs paul's first comment works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@paul correct me, and it's this way:

```
SELECT t1.title FROM myrecords as t1 where replace(title,'\\\"','@') LIKE "%@%";
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont understand how does it work. Afer using it i get two columns with @ in it.

Comment: with that, you are replacing every \" for @, and you are making the search by @, I wasn't sure if it was going to work, can you create part of the table here: http://sqlfiddle.com/ to test

Comment: I guess you mean to have a `HAVING` clause instead of a `WHERE` clause. But then you are still missing an alias for your `replace(...)` column. If it works, it's not a nice solution, sorry.

Comment: @tombom I tried as I could and it works for me, but I need a real example

Comment: The query in this form won't work. You can't filter with `WHERE` anything that you "create" in your `SELECT`. When you don't have rows with "@" in column "title", the result of this query will be `NULL`

Comment: yes, he meant something like this:

`SELECT t1.title FROM myrecords as t1 where replace(title,'\\\"','@') LIKE "%@%";`

Comment: LOL!, you are right!, thank @paul, I wrote it wrong!(next time edit my comment)...., but is it work? that's the most important

Comment: The second query you wrote works like a charm. Please remove the first one so that it will not confuse other people pls thx.

Comment: @tomaszs I'm glad we helped you

Answer (score 0):

This is the right query to search for `\"` :

```
SELECT * FROM myrecords where TITLE LIKE '%\\\\\\\"%';
```

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

> "To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against. "